There are four fundamental forces. Which one the exchange force caused by fermion closing to each other belongs to?
We know every force in the world can be explained as one of the four fundamental forces. For example, the support force of a table top against a wooden block is intrinsically the electromagnetic force. So which one the exchange force caused by fermion closing to each other belongs to? My friend told me a looks-reasonable explanation: "Force is an effect. Some of them result from interaction, some are not. The exchange force is a quantum effect, not caused by interaction. The same goes for inertial force produced by rotation of body." Is my friend right? By the way, is it true that the inertial force doesn't caused by interaction? Is there any force not caused by interaction?

This question is similar to: What does it mean to say exchange "force" is not really a force?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi Aqua and welcome to the Physics SE :-). For an explanation of how the EM force creates the exchange force see my answer to Is the electromagnetic force responsible for contact forces?.
